# Тренировочные задачи по JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Где взять интересные, а главное не тривиальные задачки по JavaScript?

Comment: как пользователя JavaScript на уровне тривиальных jQuery-задач, меня тоже интересует этот вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот посмотри [Quizful - тесты онлайн](http://www.quizful.net/test)
Тут тесты. Для тренировки вообще норм. Проверить себя да и попрактиковаться.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо=)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.free-lance.ru/

http://learn.javascript.ru/

Нужно разобрать все тривиальные, так как не тривиальные это свокупность нескольких тривиальных.

Answer (score -1):

Для меня было проблемой, что нет ресурсов на русском.
Нашел крутой сайт **http://javascript-tasks.ru/**

Все на русском, на разные уровни сложности.